# Covering space of an orientable manifold

Tags: manifolds

I want to show that every covering space of an orientable manifold is an orientable manifold. My definition of orientability is throw homology. It's a new notion for me, I need help... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I started typing to answer your question, I realized that I had already answered the same question some time ago. So here is a perfectly fine answer to your question using the homology definition: [How to show the covering space of an orientable manifold is orientable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055953/how-to-show-the-covering-space-of-an-orientable-manifold-is-orientable/1057158#1057158)

Regard this answer as a kind invite to search MSE for a second before asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

I have just read the texts about orientation in Hatcher's Algebraic topology and tried to give a proof purely by the definition there.

Proof.
$\;$ Let $\pi\colon N\to M$ be a covering of an orientable $n$-manifold $M$. Fix an orientation $x\mapsto \mu_x$ of $M$. For each $\widetilde{x}\in N$ a lift of $x$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which is homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which lifts to $\widetilde{U}$, and $\pi|_{\widetilde{U}}$ is a homeomorphism. We have isomorphisms $$H_n(\widetilde{U}|\widetilde{x})\overset{i_*}{\longrightarrow}H_n(N|\widetilde{x}),\ H_n(U|x)\overset{i_*}{\longrightarrow} H_n(M|x),$$ by excision. Then we define a map $\widetilde{x}\mapsto \mu_{\widetilde{x}}$ where $\mu_{\widetilde{x}}$ is the image of $\mu_x$ under the isomorphism $$H_n(M|x)\overset{(i_*)^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} H_n(U|x)\overset{(\pi_*)^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} H_n(\widetilde{U}|\widetilde{x})\overset{i_*}{\longrightarrow} H_n(N|\widetilde{x}).$$
To show the map is well defined, suppose $U,V$ are two such neighborhoods of $x$, WLOG, we may assume that $V\subset U$ and it suffices to show that we are assigning to $\widetilde{x}$ the same local orientation by the above construction using $U, V$ respectively. Consider the following diagram
[image]

where the $i_*$'s are all induced by inclusion and are isomorphisms. Commutativity is clear and that will get it done.

To see the map satisfies the local consistency condition, consider the following diagram
[image]

where $B\subset U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ such that $\overline{B}\subset U$ and for each $y\in B$ the local orientation $\mu_y$ is the image of one choosen generator $\mu_B$ under $H_n(M|B)\to H_n(M|y)$. The four outer horizonal isomorphisms come from excision and they are all induced by inclusions, the middle $\pi_*$'s are isomorphisms since $\pi$ restrict to homeomorphisms on the corresponding subsets, and commutativity of the diagram is clear. By the construction above, $\mu_y$ correspondes to $\mu_{\widetilde{y}}$ under the lower horizonal isomorphisms, then we conclude that $\mu_{\widetilde{y}}$ is the image of $\mu_{\widetilde{B}}$ under the natural map $i_*\colon H_n(N|\widetilde{B})\to H_n(N|\widetilde{y})$, where $\mu_{\widetilde{B}}$ is the generator corresponding to $\mu_B$ under the upper horizonal isomorphisms.