# Can the Klein bottle cover the torus? Show the Klein bottle can't be covered by a space $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm brushing up on covering spaces for an upcoming exam, and I came across the following problems related to the Klein bottle:

> 1. Can there exist a cover of the torus by the Klein bottle?

and

> 2. Let $X$ be a connected and locally path connected space with $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Show the Klein bottle cannot be covered by $X$.

I'm mainly looking for hints here, not necessarily full solutions. For (1), should I be looking at the Galois correspondence for covers of the torus? And for (2), do I also want to look at the Galois correspondence, or would it be easier to show that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ does not embed into the fundamental group of the Klein bottle $\langle a,b\mid abab^{-1}\rangle$?

Am I on the right track for these, or should I be doing something else?

Comment: No because there is no injection $\Bbb Z/2\to\Bbb Z$

Comment: Are you talking about (1)? Why does it follow from that?

Comment: @AndresMejia I know that, but I don't see what that has to do with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. The fundamental group of the torus is not $\mathbb{Z}$, and the fundamental group of the Klein bottle is not $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: I meant $\Bbb Z^2$ (and any homomorphism must pass through the abelianization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you ask for hints:

The easiest way (in my mind) to see the answer to $1$ is "no" is that
[covering spaces of an orientable space are orientable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055953/how-to-show-the-covering-space-of-an-orientable-manifold-is-orientable). If you like, you can consider fundamental groups instead. If $K$ covered $T$, then by the galois correspondence we would need to have $\pi_1 K$ as a subgroup of $\pi_1 T$. But every map from $\pi_1 K = \langle a, b \mid abab^{-1} \rangle$ to $\pi_1 T$ sends $a \mapsto 0$. Do you see why?

For your second question, I think your idea with embeddings of fundamental groups is a good one. It's "well known" that $\pi_1 K$ is torsion free. In particular, there are no elements of order $3$. Can you show this? It's a bit tricky, so I'll leave a hint under the fold:

> Can you show $\pi_1 K = \mathbb{Z} \ltimes \mathbb{Z}$? Is it clear that *this* is torsion free? It might be helpful to rewrite $\pi_1 K = \langle a, b \mid bab^{-1} = a^{-1} \rangle$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^